# cambiar colores a mapa en excel 2010 con una macro en vba

Tags: vba, macros, excel-2010

Tengo un mapa en vectores, separado cada municipio el cual se colorea según datos de una tabla, esto se hace por medio de una macro. Funciona bien pero quiero cambiar los colores ya que son muy fuertes y quiero poder poner colores pastel o si es posible elegir en rgb lo que yo desee. Estube buscando informacion pero no encuentro como hacerlo, El codigo es el siguiente.

```js
Sub Mapa()

Dim municipio As String
For i = 2 To 47

municipio = Cells(i, 9)
colores = Cells(i, 11)

ActiveSheet.Shapes(municipio).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = colores

Next i

Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 43
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 44
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 45
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 46

End Sub
```

Estuve investigando y encontre que se puede emplear algo así

> Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(200,160,27)

lo pongo después del `next i` pero no me funciona, entiendo que es ahí donde se define el color, o estoy mal?

[Este es el post que me sirvió para hacer el ejemplo que ya tengo.](http://trucosycursos.es/representar-tus-datos-mapa-excel/)

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, de antemano gracias!

Comment: En el enlace que has puesto, dice claramente cómo cambiar los colores en la sección *Podemos modificar los colores aplicados al mapa por el número de indice de la paleta de colores:*. En alguna celda tienes que meter esos números (43,44,45,36), no en el propio código.

Comment: Se supone debería hacerlo pero no es así, y no entiendo por qué no lo hace.